# Can't figure out how to get view/layout width/height

Tags: android

I'm an Android newbie.  This should be the easiest thing in the world, but figuring it out is driving me batty: how do I get the dimensions of a view or layout?

The standard approach seems to be something along the lines of:

((LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.MyLayout)).getWidth();

Except that this always returns zero, since I'm trying to do this when the Activity starts up (onCreate) and the geometry isn't set yet.  I tried putting in sleeps to give it a chance to set up the layout, except that it *won't* set up the layout until onCreate returns.  So it's clearly not threaded.  :P

I found a bunch of pages talking about overriding all sorts of different callback functions in order to be sure that the layout is loaded when you call getWidth -- but all of them threw errors when I tried to put the overrides in my Activity.  So I can assume that they were callbacks for the layouts and/or views being measured.  The problem with that is that I'm not using custom view/layout classes -- just the standard ones.  So I can't just add an override, as far as I know.

Anyone know what I should do?  I've spent something like 8 hours on this problem and gotten nowhere.  And it's something that's normally such a trivial thing to do in most development environments!

Answer (score 22):

```
final View view = .....; // your view

view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // make sure it is not called anymore 
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // your code to get dimensions of the view here:
        // ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: Interesting.  But it's not working for me.

"The method onGlobalLayout of type new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){} must override a superclass method"

Thoughts?

Comment: Make sure all neccessary interfaces and classes are imported.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for me, and I think it better than using onWindowFocusChanged !

Comment: It's worked, thanks. But removeGlobalOnLayoutListener is deprecated. I used removeOnGlobalLayoutListener.

Answer (score 1):

Why not [`View.getLayoutParams()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29)? It has `public int height` and `public int width`.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but putting it here for others. 
Try overriding onWindowFocusChanged. You should be able to get the measured width/height of the view in there.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it durring `onStart()`? This method is called after `onCreate()` has finished executing, meaning the layout has been inflated. [android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, it didn't seem to work -- it still returns zero.  And this is being called on the main layout of the app defined in the xml file, which is set to fill_parent for both width and height.

Any other hypotheses?

Comment: As a followup, I put a sleep so I could see what the screen looked like on onStart.  It was all black, nothing drawn.  I also tried onResume, but it still was black there, too.

Comment: One more followup: I tried one more technique -- getLayoutParams() in onStart.  It says the width is "-1".  :P

Answer (score -1):

I have a work-around where I use:

```
view.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), 500);
```

which runs the logic in MyRunnable 500 ms from now. This allows onCreate or whatever lifecycle method to return and drawing to occur so that I can get the correct height and width. But it is also ugly as the user can see the delay.

Comment: Why to provide such solution where you can find a better one above?!