# How to get tab's content's height and width in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I want to get the tab content i.e. framelayout's height and width in the first tab's activity. But it always returns 0. I know that we cannot call getHeight() or getMeasuredHeight() in onCreate() because the view isnt drawn yet, but then when to call it ? In activity I dont have access to onDraw or onMeasure method, so how and when can I access the height and width ?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581753/cant-figure-out-how-to-get-view-layout-width-height solved my problem. However, I would like to know when the onGlobalLayout() is actually called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html  You can refer to this ....

Note : The `onGlobalLayout()` will be called if there is

1. Any changes in the view like change in **Screen Orientation**
2. Any changes in layout while **scrolling** or while hiding some widgets, this method will be called